# How To Display A Unique Element Based On A Click Event In Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I have two files. An app.component.ts file and an app.component.html file.

Below is an image example of what I want to achieve in my User Interface.

[image: Action Icon Displaying Nav Element]

If you look at the photo, you'll see an action icon by the right displaying a nav box element.

I tried achieving something similar in my angular application and this is what I get any time I click on the action Icon:

[image: Total Display of action nav]

All the nav boxes display on the UI when I click on the icon. This is because the nav element is inside a `*ngFor` loop.

Here is my code in the `app.component.html` file:

```
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let picture of pictures">
      <div class="cell">
        <p>{{picture.name}}</p>
        <p class="med-text meta space-text">{{picture.ticketid}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cell"><p class="meta">{{picture.email}}</p></div>
      <div class="cell-photo"><p class="meta">{{picture.ticket_type}}</p></div>
      <div class="cell-large">
        <div class="toggle on">
          <div class="toggle"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        <div>
<div class="toggle-on" (click)="toggleActionNav()">
        <div class="action"></div
          </div>


<!--- nav-Element Starts ---->
        <nav  class="dropdown-list w-dropdown-list w--open" *ngIf ="actionNav">
            <div>View Pictures</div>
            <div >Edit Pictures</div>
          </nav>
<!--- nav-Element Ends ---->

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the code on my `app.component.ts` file:

```
actionNav: boolean;

 toggleActionNav() {
    this.actionNav = !this.actionNav;
  }
```

My question goes thus. How do I get the nav elements to display uniquely and not all displaying together at the same time, just like it is in the first photo?

All responses will be deeply appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can use Angular Material to do this. The component is called a menu https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview

Comment: I'm not allowed to use angular material.

Answer (score 2):

You can, for example, add a `showActionNav` property to your picture object. Then you can do `(click)="picture.showActionNav = !picture.showActionNav"` to toggle it and `*ngIf ="picture.showActionNav"` to display it.

Comment: I'm getting the object from a Rest API, so I can't add a property to it.

Comment: Thanks. I got the behavior I wanted from the nav element.

Answer (score 1):

#### simplest answer would be just set flag,

for example, `actionNavOpen` in your object:

1. `(click)="picture.actionNavOpen = !picture.actionNavOpen"`
2. in navs ngIf do: `*ngIf ="picture.actionNavOpen"`

of course if you're heavily typed this will give you some errors.

#### so few tips what to do next:

- toggling of this flag (`actionNavOpen`) should be via method
- in this method you can also set all others flag in `pictures` to false
- just remember you don't need to pre-set this flag to falsy - it's already falsy while you get this data from rest api
- to remove type errors you should extend returning model (interface) from rest api with your model which has this particular flag (`actionNavOpen`)

Comment: ...and the simplest answer got me exactly what I wanted.Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

if you could show the before and after image will help to understand the problem. Here the problem statement given , when clicking the icons overlap or design itself is overlapping ?

Comment: The problem is that, all the Nav Elements get displayed instead of the specific one that is being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

actionNav variable shouldn't be in component's scope. It should be part of picture object which you are using in the ngFor.

And, pass the picture object along with index to the toggleActionNav method to change the actionNav value.
Below is what you need.

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let (picture, index) of pictures">
    <div class="cell">
        <p>{{picture.name}}</p>
        <p class="med-text meta space-text">{{picture.ticketid}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <p class="meta">{{picture.email}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-photo">
        <p class="meta">{{picture.ticket_type}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-large">
        <div class="toggle on">
            <div class="toggle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="small">
        <div>
            <div class="toggle-on" (click)="toggleActionNav(picture, index)">
                <div class="action"></div>
            </div>
            <!--- nav-Element Starts ---->
            <nav class="dropdown-list w-dropdown-list w--open" *ngIf="picture.actionNav">
                <div>View Pictures</div>
                <div>Edit Pictures</div>
            </nav>
            <!--- nav-Element Ends ---->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the toggle method needs to be like:

```
toggleActionNav(picture, index) {
  //disable all the actionNavs to false
  this.pictures.map(pictureObj => pictureObj.actionNav = false)
  this.pictures[index] = true
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error from the html template:

```
Unexpected token (, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 5 in [let (picture, index) of pictures]
```

Comment: My mistake. Change the ngFor to <div class="row" *ngFor="let picture of pictures; let idx=index">

And pass the idx variable to your method.
<div class="toggle-on" (click)="toggleActionNav(picture, idx)">